# Doctrine 2: сохранение коллекции связанных сущностей как simple_array (или что-нибудь в таком духе)

Tags: php, doctrine2

Есть сущности Parent и Child. Parent должен содержать отсортированный список Child'ов. Возможно ли обойтись без таблицы их связей и сохранить список в какой-нибудь simple_array, сохранив при этом маппинг?

```
create table `parents` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `children` varchar(255) not null comment 'CSV',
    ...
)

create table `children` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    ...
)

select `id`, `children` from `parents`;

+----+----------+
| id | children |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 1,2,3    |
+----+----------+
```

Объекты Child могут содержать много чего интересного (связи с другими сущностями, например) и просто сериализовать их не вариант.

Связь нужна односторонняя:

```
$parent = $em->find('Parent', 1);
$parent->getChildren(); // получить Child[] или типа того
```

Как провернуть такое в доктрине?

Comment: Но зачем так извращаться? Что там вам таблица - дисковое пространство съест? А потом будете крутить костыли чтобы нормально работать.

Comment: @u_mulder ну само по себе это не извращение. Я просто надеюсь, что существует некостыльное решение в доктрине. Лишнего вообще стараюсь избегать, оно съедает внимание разработчика :-)

Comment: Так как это противоречит здравому смыслу и правилам нормализации, то я сомневаюсь, что разработчики доктрины стали бы реализовывать поддержку такого подхода.

Comment: Но можно попробовать создать свой тип данных доктрины и как-то в нем добавить такую логику. Правда, в тип данных придется прокидывать энтити-менеджер, но раз пошла такая пьянка.

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал делать так, как хотите вы. Если у children будет 10 000 записей, то ваших 255 символов не хватит. К тому же никакого контроля целостности, когда как FK всегда поможет

Comment: @ArchDemon  очевидно, что тип поля выбирается соответственно представлениям о данных, которые планируется хранить. varchar(255) просто для иллюстрации. Денормализация же нужна для случая, когда целостность данных не является приоритетом. Помощь FK не требуется.